# Is there any tool replacement for SONAR for .net code quality and generate report from it?

Tags: c#-4.0, sonarqube, fxcop

I have a Visual studio solution, which is designed using c# 4.0 .

I want to check the code quality for my solution and generate report out of it.

I tried the FxCop and i also got the report but i need the report something like this(from the image).

The rules compliance is 85% but in FxCop it only showed me the critical, error, etc.

I was not able to even deploy my project into SONAR because I had some timeout issue

coming for one of my project in the solution.

please someone help me.

[image: SONAR report]

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Roopini

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's an equivalent of SonarQube for .NET projects, but if you really want such reporting (which I can understand, obviously!), you should rather ask questions on how to resolve your installation issue for SonarQube instead of searching for something else. There are plenty of organizations where big .NET solutions are successfully analyzed with SonarQube and the C# plugins, so there's no reason why it can't work for you!

You can find useful material on the net to help you on this. For instance, a blog post written by John M Wright about ["setting up SonarQube for C# projects"](http://www.wrightfully.com/setting-up-sonar-analysis-for-c-projects/). John periodically updates his post, so the information should still be very relevant.

Comment: okay, is there any link that I can refer to for any particular organization?

Comment: I can't give you this information, these are SonarSource customers. But I'll edit my anwser to add a link to John M. Wright's blog on which he gives useful information for .NET developers.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, this link was useful.

Comment: I do try to keep the post updated with major releases, and will also try to respond to any comments you post.

Comment: @  John M. Wright- thanks John, I shall try the steps you told me in mail and let you know for any help needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)? It generates interactive reports about .NET code quality and code rules compliance. Here are some [sample reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx).

NDepend is also a tool integrated in Visual Studio (2017, 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010) that proposes a range of interactive features ([graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx), [code metrics visualization](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Treemap.aspx), [code diff](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Diff.aspx)...). Another point about NDepend is that code rules are actually C# LINQ queries, so it is pretty easy to customize a [default code rule](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) or create your own code rules.

NDepend also [integrates in VS Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndepend.ndependextension) and you'll get all code quality data from your VSTS UI instead of being redirected to a server.

I read that you have time-out problems analyzing your code base, maybe it is because your code base is pretty large. NDepend is optimized and it can analyze a very large code base and create a report in a few dozens of seconds (it takes around a minute to analyze the whole .NET Fx).
[A 14 days full featured trial is available.](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx)

*Disclaimer: I work in the NDepend team*

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I would suggest taking a look at my blog post on setting up SonarQube for C# projects: http://www.wrightfully.com/setting-up-sonar-analysis-for-c-projects/

The key to fixing your issue will be determining what the system is doing when the timeout occurs.  Take a look at your log files and see what the last lines were before it timed out.  It could be that your code is complex and just needs more time, in which case you can adjust the timeout values for whichever tool is running at the time.

Otherwise, I would suggest running whichever analysis tool (fxcop, gendarme, sytlecop, etc) was running when the timeout occurred outside of SonarQube.  That is, run the tool directly from the commandline to see if it still times out or provides any additional information on the console.

Also, assuming you're using the sonar-runner tool to execute the SonarQube analysis, you can add the -X argument to the commandline, which will run it with debug-level logging enabled. This will create a LOT more log messages which may shed some additional light on the issue.

Comment: @roopni - I'm posting the content of my email reply to your question along these lines (so that others that come across this SO post can benefit from it)